# How can I move a layout or card view when an action is made

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

I have created my expandable and collapsable card views in android studios by changing the visibility of the expandable card view. (So if it is visible it has expanded and if not visible it is collapsed, each card view has a state of whether it is expanded or collapsed.) 
But when a card view is expanded it is then underneath the next card view. What is a possible way I can push the collapsed card views away from the expanded card view?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp" --> the extra 100dp for the expanded view
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp"> --> this allows the card views to be underneath each other when not expanded
....

</LinearLayout>
```

My code in the adapter for the card view...

```
private void onClickButton(final CardView expandableLayout, final       
LinearLayout mainlayout, final int i){

    if (expandableLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
        expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        expandState.put(i,false);
    }
    else{
        expandableLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // ideally mainlayout. 
        // something to change the   android:layout_marginBottom="0" ?
        expandState.put(i,true);
    }
}
```

I am thinking that I would need to implement some code to change the main layouts parameter when it is visible and when it is not visible, I just can't find the code to use.

Comment: set elevation for the cardview when it is expanded

Comment: This doesn't seem to work it sets the expandable card view above the card view it is being expanded from (two card views in the linear layout I posted above) but not the others I would think this is to do with the fact that they are created in a recycled view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have set your Linear Layout to

```
android:layout_height="200dp"
```

The Linear Layout Can't expand Beyond 200dp

Try 'wrap_content' for LinearLayout Height

And Better is to Calculate Each Height.

When You Expand the View, It Expands to Whatever Height the Other Views have + an Extra Height for the CardView

Use ValueAnimator to Animate the Heights like Below:

```js
ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(YOUR_LINEAR_LAYOUT.getHeight(), getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.YOUR_DESIRED_HEIGHT));
anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
    int Val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams param = YOUR_LINEAR_LAYOUT.getLayoutParams();
    param.height = Val;
    YOUR_LINEAR_LAYOUT.setLayoutParams(param);
  }
});

anim.setInterpolator(YOUR_DESIRED_INTERPOLATOR);
anim.setDuration(DURATION).start();
```

You Can Even Use Several Value Animator Inside an `AnimatorSet`

Comment: Ok awesome I see it is a simple as using wrap content and then I can leave the card view dimensions as defined. I also had to get rid of android:layout_marginBottom="-100dp". I haven't tried the animator but will do.

Comment: yeah, let me know if you need more elaboration and code examples